# Preventing Segue Until User Dismisses Ad?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, segue

I am integrating interstital ads to a few segues in my app.

Issue is the interstital loads and then is instantly voided by the segue triggering.

Is there a method so pause the function to not run the segue until the advert is closed? Thats the only way  I can think to resolve this. Code is below:

```
@IBAction func closeExerciseDetails(_ sender: Any) {
    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        self.interstitial = self.createAd()
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToExercisesSegue", sender: self)
}
```

EDIT: New code that isnt working...

```
@IBAction func closeExerciseDetails(_ sender: Any) {
    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        self.interstitial = self.createAd()
    }
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToExercisesSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a delegate for this:

```
- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
}
```

You can just perform the segue in this delegate.

Comment: what would this be in swift? i cant find it?

Comment: func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
}

Comment: This isnt working sorry, i added the func and it still instantly dismisses, updated my OP,  the segue doesnt work...

Comment: Please look into this,

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/interstitial

You might not have implemented the delegates correctly for admob, please review the official documentation on the link provided.

Before presenting the interstitial, you need to set its delegate using this

interstitial.delegate = self

Comment: that doesnt really address using a button to dismiss with segue? its about a different usage